# Why is pull-up resistor disabled in OUTPUT mode

Tags: microcontroller, pullup

I noticed in a lot of micro datasheets that the internal pull-up resistor is disabled automatically when the GPIO is in OUTPUT mode, but I'm not sure I understand why. Is a pull up resistor never needed in OUTPUT mode? Appreciate the explanation

Comment: "Is a pull up resistor never needed in OUTPUT mode?" Yes, it is never needed.

Answer (score 5):

If the output is in output mode, it is either driving high or low.

If it's driving high, then a pull-up does little to increase the available current pushing the output high.

If it's driving low, then a pull-up just increases power consumption and makes the output sink more current to keep the output low.

Answer (score 1):

In output mode, microcontrollers are configured in Push-Pull (typically), so they are actively driving it. Only in cases of open Drain do you want/need a pull-up.

You can see this basically in CMOS as a PMOS and NMOS transistors, each driving the output HIGH or LOW. A pullup will cause the NMOS transistor at the bottom to have to fight to drive the voltage to 0, wasting power.

You can look at the image below that shows a digital CMOS output stage (actually an inverter acting as a buffer).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8Dl8k.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: @ThePhoton You're right. I didn't look at the question good enough and assumed something different.

Comment: "Only in cases of open Drain do you want/need a pull-up." Is this device specific? Sorry if that's a stupid question, but do certain microcontrollers have open Drain outputs where you would need a pull-up in OUTPUT no matter what?

Comment: @user28915: Not per se, but use of an internal pullup removes/reduces the need for an external pullup on e.g. SPI or I2C connections.

Comment: So I ask, because I was given a situation where a certain microcontrollers internal pull-up resistor is disabled, but I'm using the GPIO to drive a BJT and I cannot find in the datasheet if the GPIO is open drain. I hope that makes sense..

Comment: @user28915: GPIOs are push-pull unless otherwise specified.

Comment: @user28915: In the 8051, port 0 is open drain.  you would have to study the datasheet for the microcontoller you are using to determine if it has any open-driain output ports.